# Application hanged when lots of data are loaded to the gridview

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview, tooltip

I have a gridview in windows form. When lots of data are loaded from the database to the gridview, my application hang until all the data are loaded to the gridview. Is there any way to solve this problem? I also want to display a gif image [loading.gif] or progressbar when data is being loading to the gridview to show the user that data is being loading to the gridview. But the image and progressbar also hang.

I have also one ToolTip, I want to display that tooltip in the center of the screen. My code is as follow but it is not positioning that tooltip in the center.

```
    Dim x As Integer = TryCastInteger(Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width / 2)
    Dim y As Integer = TryCastInteger(Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height /2)
    ToolTip1.Show("It will take few seconds to display the data.", KryptonPanel1, x, y)
```

Answer (score 2):

For the first part of your question : Create a [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xs8549b.aspx)  thread to load data from database and populate these data on gridview on main thread without freezing your UI.

Comment: And use ProgressChanged on the BackgroundWorker to update the image and progressbar.

Answer (score 0):

You are loading data in the UI thread - that's why it freezes your UI until it's done.

Have a look at asynchronous data binding.

Here's some links:

[Asynchronous data loading and data binding with Windows Forms](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/AsyncDataloading.aspx)

[StackOverflow - Asynchronously populate datagridview in Windows Forms application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357463/asynchronously-populate-datagridview-in-windows-forms-application)

Comment: looks to me like you're not using background worker the right way. you should do get data in DoWork method (without updating the UI) and then pass the result to WorkCompleted mothod and there update the UI